# Firebase 3.0 authentication with AngularJS application

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an AngularJS application that I have been using with Firebase to persist data.

Now I have been working toward refactoring my auth code per Firebase 3.0 guidelines.

The problem that I am facing is that upon login, the 'classifieds' state defined in the app.js file does not load. The console does not throw any error as well.

In my application, I would like my user to be directed to the login page at the first instance. so for this i have the following code in my app.js file. I haven't refactored any code in this file. Please let me know if this is the issue.

```
angular
.module('ngClassifieds', ['ngMaterial', 'ui.router', 'firebase'])


.run(["$rootScope", "$state", function($rootScope, $state) {
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
  // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireAuth promise is rejected
  // and redirect the user back to the home page
  if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
    $state.go("auth");
  }
});
}])

    .config(function($mdThemingProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $mdThemingProvider
        .theme('default')
        .primaryPalette('blue-grey')
        .accentPalette('orange')
//      .backgroundPalette('blue-grey');


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/auth');

    $stateProvider
        .state('auth', {
          url: '/auth',
          templateUrl: 'components/auth/auth.tpl.html',
          controller: 'authCtrl',

        })


    $stateProvider
        .state('classifieds', {
            url: '/notes', 
            templateUrl: 'components/classifieds/classifieds.tpl.html',
            controller: 'classifiedsCtrl',
            resolve: {
              // controller will not be loaded until $requireAuth resolves
              // Auth refers to our $firebaseAuth wrapper in the example above
              "currentAuth": ["auth", function(auth) {
                // $requireAuth returns a promise so the resolve waits for it to complete
                // If the promise is rejected, it will throw a $stateChangeError (see above)
                return auth.ref.$requireAuth();
              }]
            }

        })
```

The following is my auth.ctr.js file:

```
(function() {

  "use strict";

  angular
    .module('ngClassifieds')
    .controller('authCtrl', function($scope, auth, $state, $firebaseAuth) {

      var auth = $firebaseAuth();


     $scope.login = function() {

        auth
          .$signInWithEmailAndPassword($scope.email, $scope.password)
          .then(function(result) {
            $state.go('classifieds');
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            $scope.error = error;
          });
      }

  });

})();
```

The following is my auth.fac.js:

```
(function() {

  "use strict";

  angular
    .module('ngClassifieds')
    .factory('auth', function($firebaseAuth) {


      function signOut() {
        return firebase.auth().signOut()
          .then(function() {
            console.log('signed out')
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }

      return {
        signOut: signOut
      }

    });

})();
```

Also, my index.html has the necessary info per firebase 3.0 documentation:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.9/firebase.js"></script>


<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "XXX",
    authDomain: "XXX.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://XXXX.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "XXX.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "XXX"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.3.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

I'd appreciate any guidance on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Please add a plunker or something similar that reproduces this problem. It's very hard to debug it like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication issue with migrating AngularJS application and Firebase 2.x.x to Firebase 3.x.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137906/authentication-issue-with-migrating-angularjs-application-and-firebase-2-x-x-to)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the first parameter of the "$rootScope.$on(...)" function. Well $stateChangeError is depricated. In fact all state events, are now deprecated and disabled by default. See this link it may helps you : https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/ng1_state_events.html. ALso this link, you'll probably find the solution here : https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0

Comment: you'll nedd to add 
 <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/stateEvents.js"></script> to your insex.html file